# How do I get results from past 1 hour in sql

Tags: sql

I have this query to get all caseids that are less than 10 chars and do not have a T in front from the past hour:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PICKDETAIL 
WHERE LENGTH(CASEID) <> 10 
  AND CASEID NOT LIKE 'T%' 
  AND TO_CHAR(editdate, 'hh24mi') > TO_CHAR(sysdate - 1/24, 'hh24mi');
```

But when I run this I will still get results from days ago.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert to a string.  Just use date comparisons:

```
SELECT pd.*
FROM PICKDETAIL pd
WHERE LENGTH(pd.CASEID) <> 10 AND
      pd.CASEID NOT LIKE 'T%' AND 
      pd.editdate > sysdate - 1/24;
```